# Change Default Font Size in embedded Power BI table?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

client-react. Is there a way to change font size using react power bi react settings?

```
<PowerBIEmbed
embedConfig = {{
    type: 'report',   // Supported types: report, dashboard, tile, visual and qna
    id: '<Report Id>',
    embedUrl: '<Embed Url>',
    accessToken: '<Access Token>',
    tokenType: models.TokenType.Embed,
    settings: {
        panes: {
            filters: {
                expanded: false,
                visible: false
            }
        },
        background: models.BackgroundType.Transparent,
    }
}}
```

[Power BI npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/powerbi-client-react)

My app looks like [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fX3C5.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have to define class in **cssClassName** props

```
<PowerBIEmbed cssClassName = { "style-class-font-size" }
embedConfig = {{
    type: 'report',   // Supported types: report, dashboard, tile, visual and qna
    id: '<Report Id>',
    embedUrl: '<Embed Url>',
    accessToken: '<Access Token>',
    tokenType: models.TokenType.Embed,
    settings: {
        panes: {
            filters: {
                expanded: false,
                visible: false
            }
        },
        background: models.BackgroundType.Transparent,
    }
}}
```

And you can define you css class like this :

```
.style-class-font-size { 
    font-size:24px;
}
```

Comment: Don't know why but it does not work. 1) I have props with styles [![pic 1][1]][1]
2) my css [![pic2][2]][2]
3) transfer pro from here [![pic 3][3]][3]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkVN0.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSZbN.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1i9h.png